# Compare element height after an event in Protractor or Selenium

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor

I'm writing a Protractor test with Jasmine to compare the height of an element before and after a button is clicked. Clicking the button makes the element smaller.

```
let heightBefore: number;
$('#my-element').getSize().then((size) => {
    heightBefore = size.height;
});

$('#my-button').click();

let heightAfter: number;
$('#my-element').getSize().then((size) => {
    heightAfter = size.height;
});

expect(heightBefore).toBeLessThan(heightAfter);
```

The problem with this code is that the expect function runs before the `heightBefore` and `heightAfter` variables have been set, because the promises returned by `getSize()` haven't resolved yet.

How can I get Protractor to wait until the height values are available before running the expectation?